# How to get the data of video in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

How to get the `video` details using `document.getElementById`, is it possible in `react-native`. Cna we use `refs` here
i'm new to react native please help me thanks in advance

```
const videoDetails = document.getElementByid("video")

<View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
   <Video id ="video" source={{uri: "background"}} style= {styles.backgroundVideo} />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it actually depends on which kind of data you want to retrieve from your video.

If you are referring to metadata well, you should probably look at another NPM module (maybe [react-native-media-meta](https://github.com/mybigday/react-native-media-meta) should help).

If you want to retrieve data about each scene of your video you probably must look at something different which requires a little bit more of development and research (an AI for example could help you with what you're interested in).